How to prevent the Gnome terminal from closing on a mouse middle button click on its window application tab?
I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS in Lubuntu with LXQt and the Openbox window manager.
stephane@stephane-20jts0cv0v:~$ neofetch
           `-mddhhhhhhhhhddmss`             stephane@stephane-20jts0cv0v 
        ./mdhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh.         ---------------------------- 
     :mdhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhm`       OS: Lubuntu 22.04.4 LTS x86_64 
   :ymhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhyyyyyyhhhhhhhhhy:      Host: 20JTS0CV0V ThinkPad T470s W10DG 
  `odhyyyhhhhhhhhhy+-````./syhhhhhhhho`     Kernel: 6.5.0-35-generic 
 `hhy..:oyhhhhhhhy-`:osso/..:/++oosyyyh`    Uptime: 7 days, 19 hours, 42 mins 
 dhhs   .-/syhhhhs`shhhhhhyyyyyyyyyyyyhs    Packages: 2113 (dpkg), 8 (snap) 
:hhhy`  yso/:+syhy/yhhhhhshhhhhhhhhhhhhh:   Shell: bash 5.1.16 
hhhhho. +hhhys++oyyyhhhhh-yhhhhhhhhhhhhhs   Resolution: 1920x1080 
hhhhhhs-`/syhhhhyssyyhhhh:-yhhhhhhhhhhhhh   DE: LXQt 0.17.1 
hhhhhhs  `:/+ossyyhyyhhhhs -yhhhhhhhhhhhh   WM: Openbox 
hhhhhhy/ `syyyssyyyyhhhhhh: :yhhhhhhhhhhs   Theme: Arc-Darker [GTK2/3] 
:hhhhhhyo:-/osyhhhhhhhhhhho  ohhhhhhhhhh:   Icons: ePapirus [GTK2/3] 
 sdhhhhhhhyyssyyhhhhhhhhhhh+  +hhhhhhhhs    Terminal: gnome-terminal 
 `shhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhy+` .yhhhhhhhh`    CPU: Intel i5-6300U (4) @ 3.000GHz 
  +sdhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhyo/. `/yhhhhhhhd`     GPU: Intel Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] 
   `:shhhhhhhhhh+---..``.:+yyhhhhhhh:       Memory: 2308MiB / 7680MiB 
     `:mdhhhhhh/.syssyyyyhhhhhhhd:`
        `+smdhhh+shhhhhhhhhhhhdm`                                   
           `sNmdddhhhhhhhddm-`                                      

Sometimes, I accidentally do a middle mouse button click on the Gnome terminal application tab sitting at the bottom of the screen. That instantly closes the Gnome terminal application including all its tabs.
After many years of shooting myself in the foot, I started looking around to see if I could prevent this.
I did not find any way yet on how to achieve this.
If could be disabling the closing action, or it could be intercepting it and displaying a warning message like the Firefox browser is doing.

Are you talking about actual terminal tabs, or about the "taskbar" buttons that LXQt has? Does the terminal also close without confirmation if you close it with its own (×) button?

@grawity_u1686 I'm talking of the tabs that are in the desktop task bar at the very bottom of the screen. I'm not talking of the terminals tabs. And yes, a click on the x top right icon of the terminal window does close it all without any warning nor confirmation at all.

The common behavior/convention for a middle-click on a tab is that the tab closes. If the entire Gnome Terminal closes for you, have you considered opening a bug ticket about it?
There is a setting gtk-enable-primary-paste=true for "pasting the primary selection with a middle click". I would expect that to be behavior for middle-clicking within the terminal area though, not the tab bar.

Indeed, I'm used to pasting with a middle button click, and that's how I sometimes click not seeing the mouse cursor is sitting on the application tab. Hence the abrupt shoot down.
